# number of divisors

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $d(n,Q)$ denote the number of divisors of $n$ that is smaller than $Q$. Let $D(n,Q)$ denote the number of positive integers smaller than $Q$ that has the same prime factors with $n$.

My question is, how can we bound $\frac{D(n,Q)}{d(n,Q)}$ in terms of $n$ and $Q$?

Comment: Pure curiosity or a special reason?

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński In one of Jean Bourgain's paper, it is claimed that it is bounded by $\exp c\frac{\log Q}{\log \log Q}$ but I couldn't figure out a proof. And to avoid asking it as an exercise, there it goes.

Comment: Upper or lower bound?  How does Q relate to the largest prime factor of n?  Is n squarefree?  What motivates the problem?

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger Upper bound. No further conditions on Q and n. See my previous comment.

Comment: It seems to me that providing some of the background (e.g., the Bourgain paper to which you refer in the comments) would be helpful in answering (or at least motivating) the question. I do not think anything is gained by obscuring what is already known (to be known)...

Comment: Then assume n is squarefree and very smooth.

Comment: Take n to be the mth primorial, so mlog m is about log n.  Then for QQ at least n, d will be between k=2^m and 2k, and D will be about fQ with error plus or minus k, where f is phi(n)/n and also f is c/log p_m, c being near 1 and p_m the largest prime factor of n namely the mth prime.